# WAMP site not responding to request by machine name

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I have a WAMP installation with a website running on it. The website responds fine to requests from the address http://localhost/website/ but if I try a request to http://wampserver/website/ I get a 403 Forbidden. How do I allow access to the site by machine name both on the server and from remote PCs?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the ip address of localhost.. try http://127.0.0.1/website

you can change this in the php.ini file